# MySQL: calculate median of a derived value

Tags: mysql, sql, median

Per the title, I am attempting to calculate a median value of a derived field:

```
SELECT
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, T1.time1, T2.time2) as diff
FROM table1 T1 JOIN table2 T2 ON ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY ...
```

Calculating the average is as simple as

```
SELECT
    AVG(F.diff) as average 
FROM (
    //subquery above
) F;
```

However searching around I have not figured out a way to calculate the median, as most solutions seem to involve joining the column's table to itself. The only way for me to do that would be to type the subquery out twice. This subquery is not a very quick one, so unless someone can confirm that MySQL will optimize out the redundancy and only execute the subquery once, then I would really like to avoid that solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick using `group_concat()`, but that might not work (because of intermediate string lengths).  A better method is simply to enumerate the rows and then use conditional aggregation.  Alas, though, this requires two levels of enumeration:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, T1.time1, T2.time2) as diff,
       AVG(CASE WHEN 2*@rn IN (cnt - 1, cnt, cnt + 1 THEN value END) as median
FROM (SELECT *,
             (@max := if(@g = concat_ws(':', <group by columns>>), @max,
                         if(concat_ws(':', <group by columns>>), rn, rn)
                        )
             ) as cnt 
      FROM (SELECT . . .,
                   (@rn := if(@g = concat_ws(':', <group by columns>>), @rn + 1,
                              @g := concat_ws(':', <group by columns>>), 1, 1)
                             )
                   ) as rn
            FROM table1 T1 JOIN table2 T2 ON ... CROSS JOIN
                 (SELECT @g := '', @rn := 0) params
            WHERE ...
            ORDER BY <group by columns>, <ordering column>
           ) t CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @g1 := '', @max := -1) params
      ORDER BY <group by columns>, <ordering column desc>
     ) t
GROUP BY ...
```